# awk print empty if columns is with empty value

Tags: bash, awk

I have a output from openshift **oc get nodes** command which the result is having many column and indented with many blank spaces. I would like to print **empty** if the column is with empty value. I have tried to get result with **awk** but I'm getting many **empty** on all those spaces

awk command has tried

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^ *$/) $i="empty"} 1'
```

result from openshift **oc get nodes** command

```
NAME          STATUS                     ROLES          AGE      VERSION           STAGE   NETWORK    ZONE     ROUTER   REGISTRY   SPLUNK         DEFENDER
server0397    Ready                      master         2y208d   v1.22.8+9e95cb9           internal   mgmt                             
server0398    Ready                      master         2y208d   v1.22.8+9e95cb9           internal   mgmt                             
server0399    Ready                      master         2y208d   v1.22.8+9e95cb9           internal   mgmt                             
server005205   Ready                      worker         52d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     true     true           
server005206   Ready                      worker         51d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     true     true           
server005208   Ready                      worker         39d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     false                   
server005209   Ready                      worker         38d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     false                   
server005210   Ready                      worker         35d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     false                   
server005211   Ready                      worker         33d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     false                   
server005212   Ready                      worker         31d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     false                   
server005225   Ready                      infra,worker   81d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   app      true                    
server005226   Ready                      infra,worker   70d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   app      true                    
server005227   Ready                      worker         87d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   app      false               testinternal
server005228   Ready                      worker         87d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   app      false               testinternal
server005286   Ready                      infra,worker   66d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   app      true
server005342   Ready                      worker         82d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    dmz        app      false               testdmz        true
server005343   Ready                      worker         82d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    dmz        app      false               testdmz        true
server005344   Ready                      worker         82d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    dmz        app      false               testdmz        true
server005345   Ready                      worker         82d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    dmz        app      false               testdmz        true
```

expecting result

```
NAME          STATUS                     ROLES          AGE      VERSION           STAGE   NETWORK    ZONE     ROUTER   REGISTRY   SPLUNK         DEFENDER
server0397    Ready                      master         2y208d   v1.22.8+9e95cb9   empty   internal   mgmt     empty     empty      empty           empty     
server0398    Ready                      master         2y208d   v1.22.8+9e95cb9   empty   internal   mgmt     empty     empty      empty           empty                        
server0399    Ready                      master         2y208d   v1.22.8+9e95cb9   empty   internal   mgmt     empty     empty      empty           empty                        
server005205   Ready                      worker         52d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     true     true       empty           empty
server005206   Ready                      worker         51d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     true     true       empty           empty   
server005208   Ready                      worker         39d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     false    empty      empty           empty               
server005209   Ready                      worker         38d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     false    empty      empty           empty               
server005210   Ready                      worker         35d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     false    empty      empty           empty              
server005211   Ready                      worker         33d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     false    empty      empty           empty               
server005212   Ready                      worker         31d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   mgmt     false    empty      empty           empty               
server005225   Ready                      infra,worker   81d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   app      true     empty      empty           empty               
server005226   Ready                      infra,worker   70d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   app      true     empty      empty           empty               
server005227   Ready                      worker         87d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   app      false    empty    testinternal      empty
server005228   Ready                      worker         87d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   app      false    empty    testinternal      empty
server005286   Ready                      infra,worker   66d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    internal   app      true     empty      empty           empty
server005342   Ready                      worker         82d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    dmz        app      false    empty      testdmz        true
server005343   Ready                      worker         82d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    dmz        app      false    empty      testdmz        true
server005344   Ready                      worker         82d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    dmz        app      false    empty      testdmz        true
server005345   Ready                      worker         82d      v1.22.8+9e95cb9   test    dmz        app      false    empty      testdmz        true
```

Comment: Is it necessary that from the 5th row and from the 2nd column the entries are shifted one space to the right?

Comment: You can't use `FS=OFS=""` and expect to get useable numbered fields. l

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU awk (for the 4th arg to `split()` and `FIELDWIDTHS`) and `column`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR == 1 {
    nf = split($0,flds,FS,seps)
    for ( i=1; i<nf; i++ ) {
        wids = (i>1 ? wids " " : "") length(flds[i] seps[i])
    }
    FIELDWIDTHS = wids " *"
    $0 = $0
}
{
    for ( i=1; i<=nf; i++ ) {
        gsub(/\s/,"",$i)
        printf "%s%s", ($i ~ /\S/ ? $i : "empty"), (i<nf ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
NAME          STATUS  ROLES         AGE     VERSION          STAGE  NETWORK   ZONE  ROUTER  REGISTRY  SPLUNK        DEFENDER
server0397    Ready   master        2y208d  v1.22.8+9e95cb9  empty  internal  mgmt  empty   empty     empty         empty
server0398    Ready   master        2y208d  v1.22.8+9e95cb9  empty  internal  mgmt  empty   empty     empty         empty
server0399    Ready   master        2y208d  v1.22.8+9e95cb9  empty  internal  mgmt  empty   empty     empty         empty
server005205  Ready   worker        52d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   internal  mgmt  true    true      empty         empty
server005206  Ready   worker        51d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   internal  mgmt  true    true      empty         empty
server005208  Ready   worker        39d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   internal  mgmt  false   empty     empty         empty
server005209  Ready   worker        38d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   internal  mgmt  false   empty     empty         empty
server005210  Ready   worker        35d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   internal  mgmt  false   empty     empty         empty
server005211  Ready   worker        33d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   internal  mgmt  false   empty     empty         empty
server005212  Ready   worker        31d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   internal  mgmt  false   empty     empty         empty
server005225  Ready   infra,worker  81d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   internal  app   true    empty     empty         empty
server005226  Ready   infra,worker  70d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   internal  app   true    empty     empty         empty
server005227  Ready   worker        87d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   internal  app   false   empty     testinternal  empty
server005228  Ready   worker        87d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   internal  app   false   empty     testinternal  empty
server005286  Ready   infra,worker  66d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   internal  app   true    empty     empty         empty
server005342  Ready   worker        82d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   dmz       app   false   empty     testdmz       true
server005343  Ready   worker        82d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   dmz       app   false   empty     testdmz       true
server005344  Ready   worker        82d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   dmz       app   false   empty     testdmz       true
server005345  Ready   worker        82d     v1.22.8+9e95cb9  test   dmz       app   false   empty     testdmz       true
```

If you're using an older version of gawk that doesn't support `*` as the final `FIELDWIDTHS` value to mean "to the end of the line" then just change `FIELDWIDTHS = wids " *"` to `FIELDWIDTHS = wids " 1000"` or some other large enough number for that column's max width.

If you're happy with tab-separated output then don't pipe to `column`.

The `gsub()` is just to tidy up the messy indentation in the input fields, if you really want to get the output you show with that messyness retained then just remove the call to `gsub()`.